# Splitting the rows of a Dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
code:

import os.path
file_name = os.path.join('databricks-datasets', 'cs190', 'data-001', 'millionsong.txt')
raw_data_df = sqlContext.read.load(file_name, 'text')

sample_points = raw_data_df.take(5)
print sample_points

Example output:

[Row(1,2,3),Row(4,5,6)]
```

From this output,wanted to parse each row in the DataFrame into individual elements, using Spark's select and split methods.

```
For example, split "1,2,3" into ['1','2','3']

Code:

raw_data_df.select((explode(split(raw_data_df.value,"\s+"))))
```

But the code doesnt seem to worf as expected any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You have a dataframe with each item in a different column, they seem already separated in your "Example ouput". What do you want to split?

Comment: Maybe show a sample of your data, followed by what the desired output would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
raw_data_df.map(lambda l: l[0].select(l[0].split(",")))
```